# Advance Slider When Embedded YouTube Video is Paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, slider

**BACKGROUND**
* I'm using a great slider called [NinjaSlider](http://www.menucool.com/slider/play-youtube-vimeo-html-video-or-audio-with-ninja-slider). This slider will pause the video if you advance the slider. It has one limitation that I can see.

**PROBLEM**
* When I pause the YouTube video with either the YT player controls or by a click on the video, the slider does NOT advance forward. The plugin developer says this is not a feature, but I'm curious if those way more smarter than me know a work around?
* This plugin does have an "x" button at the top right of the video that does what I ask. My question is about the YouTube pause actions.

**QUESTION**
* Is it possible to advance the slider once a user clicks on the YouTube pause button or clicks on the video (which makes it pause)?

**CODEPEN**
http://codepen.io/zuhloobie/pen/EPqwoR

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
<div id="ninja-slider">
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="video">                                             
           <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/alIq_wG9FNk?enablejsapi=1&start=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&fs=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen data-autoplay="1">
            </iframe>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><img class="ns-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/1000x424/cccccc/ffffff&text=slide+two"></li>
      <li><img class="ns-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/1000x424/333333/ffffff&text=slide+three"></li>
      <li><img class="ns-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/1000x424/999999/ffffff&text=slide+four"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can expose the youtube player's methods if you embed it using the API rather than a standard iframe link https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: I don't think this type of functionality is possible without using the API as jmcgriz suggested.

Comment: Hmm...I think that might be outside my skillset, but I'll definitely give it a closer read and see if I can tackle it. Thanks